# How to convert dollar money to Indian currency without function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have to convert `money` with Comma separated

```
select CONVERT(varchar, CAST(250233870.06 AS MONEY), 1)
```

Result :

```
Money
250,233,870.06
```

But I want in Indian rupee format

like desired output :

```
Money
25,02,33,870.06
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Just let the client application handle the formatting.

Comment: This question does not deserve a downvote. I recommend you explain the -1.

Comment: @Adam Possibly because there is almost never a need to do formatting like this in the database.

Comment: That's for most cases and for generality. In his case, he might not HAVE to do it, he may just want to for learning purposes. Why punish him for that? I'll leave this discussion to the meta posts.

Comment: it is purely expertise purpose not for any learning purpose.how can you expect a guys  with 2000+ reputation will ask question for learning.this is a show stopper for me in my requirement @DavidG

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but this question does not show any research effort.

Comment: @TabAlleman just tell me for a simple decimal value i have converted into comma separated and now i'm asking how to convert in indian rupee format in 2008 R2 .Still what effort i need to put you suggest me

Comment: What did you find when you googled this?   You looked into collations and regional settings?  Why did the solutions you found not work for you?

Comment: i have found out the with function we can do  this and with FORMAT built in function we can achieve but i'm unable to find out suitable solution for 2008 R2 ..that's why i posted question what will experts suggest me but till now apart from giving solution ...everything is happening over here @TabAlleman

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`FORMAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh213505.aspx) if you have SQL Server 2012 or above like this.

```
SELECT FORMAT(CAST(250233870.06 AS MONEY),'N','en-in')
```

**Output**

```
25,02,33,870.06
```

Comment: yeah but how i need to do in Sql Server 2008 R2 and that's what i'm looking  for @ughai

Comment: @Jonathan Is there a reason you don't want to use a function?

Comment: @DavidG - Actually I should work in [SQL Server 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh213505%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) and above

Comment: @ughai Indeed, my mistake. Either way, it needs to be 2008.

Comment: @Jonathan - ah , didn't see your version there

Comment: @Adam function will be performance degrader and as well as i want in system built in function

Comment: sorry @ughai it is 2008 R2 version

Comment: @Jonathan Do you have a front end app to this?

Comment: @Adam i should show in the report it is simple decimal value i need to convert in Indian Rupee format..it is coming millions format i just want crores and lakhs format

Comment: @Jonathan SSRS Report Builder?

Comment: @Jonathan Just apply the formatting in the report, not in the database.

Comment: @DavidG, converting to rupees in SSRS if it is Reporting services built by Microsoft, they won't offer it. He'll have to build his own module in .net to do it.

Comment: @Adam no it is in SSMS only actually i don't US  Format i just simply want in Indian Rupee Format

Comment: @Jonathan I have no experience with SSMS only SSRS. I'll leave this conversation to the experts then.

Comment: @Jonathan How do you expect to show the data to people if it's only in SSMS?

Comment: i have written the code in Store procedure and i'm getting desired result set in US dollar format and i'm asking how to convert in rupee format @DavidG is it clear

Comment: @Jonathan We get all that, but what do you intend to do with the data after you get it in SSMS? Normally for some sort of reporting, you distribute it in SSRS or Excel for example. Do your formatting in there instead of SQL Server.

Comment: @Jonathan..can you use a `ad-hoc` loop for this purpose?